# i try to save an integer and it saves as a list, sqlite python

Tags: python, function, sqlite, tkinter, combobox

I have the following problem in this part of my code, I explain: I have a combobox that is filled directly from the database, from there I get the data, then with a button a function is executed to obtain the id of the combobox data and then save the id in the database, the problem is that when doing the sql query to obtain the id it is saved as a list and so it does not work for me I just want the integer to be saved

```
        def guardar():
            listaId = []
    


        cursor = conexion.cursor()
```

Here I made this function to make a query using the data I got from the combobox to get the id of each of the tables, but the ids are saved as lists

```
            for cilindros, empresa, tamano, pico in lista:
                
                cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM empresas WHERE empresa =?", (empresa.get(),))
                empresaId = cursor.fetchall()
                
                
                cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM tamano_precio WHERE tamano =?", (tamano.get(),))
                tamanoId = cursor.fetchall()
                
                
                cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM picos WHERE pico =?", (pico.get(),))
                picoId = cursor.fetchall()
                

                listaId.append([empresaId, tamanoId, picoId])
            
            cursor.close()
```

Here the id is stored in the database

```
            cursor2 = conexion.cursor()

            for empresaId, tamanoId, picoId in listaId:
                


                cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO cilindros(empresa_id, pico_id, tamano_id, jefesf_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (str(empresaId), str(picoId), str(tamanoId), str(guardarCedula)))
                conexion.commit()

                

            cursor2.close()
```

Here are the comboboxes, the data you get are the names of the companies, sizes and peaks

```
        ventana5 = Toplevel()
        cantidadVacios = cantidadCilindros.get() +1
        lista = []

        for cilindros in range(1, cantidadVacios):

            titulo = tk.LabelFrame(ventana5, text= f"Cilindro {cilindros}")
            titulo.pack()

            empresa = ttk.Combobox(titulo, width=11)
            empresa["values"] = emp()
            empresa.current(0)
            empresa.pack()

            tamano = ttk.Combobox(titulo, width=11)
            tamano["values"] = taman()
            tamano.current(0)
            tamano.pack()

            pico = ttk.Combobox(titulo, width=11)
            pico["values"] = pic()
            pico.current(0)
            pico.pack()


            lista.append([cilindros, empresa, tamano, pico])

        Button(ventana5, text="Guardar", command=guardar).pack()
```

This is how they are stored:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfDSA.jpg)

And this is how I want them to be saved:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61MnL.jpg)

Comment: Change those `fetchall()` to `fetchone()[0]` if you just want to get the *id* from table.  Note that it is better to cater the situation when there is no record returned.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of all the results of the SELECT query, so that you will know if there is more than 1 entry that matched your WHERE statement, and you will act upon it. while `cursor.fetchone()` returns only the first result, but in a tuple, so you want to extract the first element in it.

you can either convert your `cursor.fetchall()` statements to `cursor.fetchone()[0]` or just take the first element using `cursor.fetchall()[0][0]`, which will be slightly slower than `fetchone()[0]`.